# как можно разбить каждое слово в двумерном массиве на раздельные символы

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть двумерный массив из слов,
хотел бы разбить каждое слово на символы и чтобы эти символы тоже находились в этом двумерном массиве.

Тут вроде разбиваю, но не понятно, почему он разбивает только последний ряд

```
def split(array):
    return [char for char in array]

f = open("lol.txt", "r")
array=[]
for line in f:
    array.append(list(map(str, line.split())))

for r in range(len(array)):
    for c in range(len(array[r])):
        b = split(array[r][c])

print(array)
print(b)
```

Вот что у меня выводит

```
[['lnobrblalo'], ['medvaozmfo'], ['ovtzasbest'], ['nznekosilo'], ['iaajnnaoly'], ['kludkkkzvi'], ['ooauulaaia']]
['o', 'o', 'a', 'u', 'u', 'l', 'a', 'a', 'i', 'a']
```

Вот что содержит `lol.txt`

```
lnobrblalo
medvaozmfo
ovtzasbest
nznekosilo
iaajnnaoly
kludkkkzvi
ooauulaaia
```

Comment: Есть готовая функция `split()`

Answer (score 3):

Разбивает каждый ряд, но выводит только последний, потому что вывод происходит после цикла, а `b` в цикле каждый раз получает новое значение, предыдущее пропадает .

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю воспользоваться чуть более коротким и элегантным решением:

```
with open("lol.txt") as f:
    res = [list(line.strip()) for line in f]
```

результат:

```
In [195]: res
Out[195]:
[['l', 'n', 'o', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'l', 'a', 'l', 'o'],
 ['m', 'e', 'd', 'v', 'a', 'o', 'z', 'm', 'f', 'o'],
 ['o', 'v', 't', 'z', 'a', 's', 'b', 'e', 's', 't'],
 ['n', 'z', 'n', 'e', 'k', 'o', 's', 'i', 'l', 'o'],
 ['i', 'a', 'a', 'j', 'n', 'n', 'a', 'o', 'l', 'y'],
 ['k', 'l', 'u', 'd', 'k', 'k', 'k', 'z', 'v', 'i'],
 ['o', 'o', 'a', 'u', 'u', 'l', 'a', 'a', 'i', 'a']]
```